# How to give external library path in firebreath

Tags: plugins, browser, npapi, firebreath, clutter

I am developing clutter based plugin using **Fire breath**. I have given the path of the includes files in **flags.make** file and the .so libs are included in **link.txt** file. But my problem is that when i launch the plugin .so file which is generated under bin/project folder, then browser is displaying install missing plugin. I am confused is there any other file in the firebreath in which we need to give the external .so file path. Please suggest.

Comment: now i am able to add the external libraries. but now, when i launch the plugin , the browser displays some error related to invalid certificate. pfs.mozilla.org uses an invalid certificate.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking.  There is no flags.make or link.txt file used in FireBreath; are those related to something else?